# Things to consider to migrate on premise WCF service to Windows Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I want to migrate an existing On Premise WCF service to Windows azure without asking clients to change anything in thier application like endpoint URL, certificate etc.
PLease let me know if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

In principal - yes.

The Endpoint Url is dependant on you controlling the domain and forwarding the URL over to Azure (for us, we use a CNAME redirect to the Azure URL).  More details [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/).

For the certificate, as long as you've got an exportable version of the certificate with a Private Key, it should be a matter of uploading the certificate to the server that matches the endpoint URL.  More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg981929.aspx).

So, all in all (with these changes in place) it's just a matter of uploading the certificate, redirecting to over to Azure and then letting DNS do its thing.  If in doubt, certificates are buttons to purchase, so use that for testing purposes to prove the concept.